# How to use DRI instead of glx?

Tags: c++, c, linux, opengl, glx

**Ok my actual problem is**:

My fan is going crazy when is start a self-written simple `OpenGL` application. First i thought my graphic-card is just too bad for stuff like that. But when i noticed that my laptop with a worse hardware runs that program without any problems i started wondering.
So i run my program on two different laptops now.
One of them is a Fedora Laptop with an intelcore I7 with an on board graphic-card and the other one is a Debian with an intelcore I5 with an on board graphic-card.
Against my expectations my fedoras fan went totally crazy so i started to do some research to find the problem.
I read about `GLX` rendering and `direct rendering` of linux.
So what i did next was that i checked the output of

```
glxinfo |grep render
```

The output told me that `direct rendering` is enabled on both machines.
The only difference is that the `OpenGL renderer string`.

On my debian it contains something like

```
mesa dri
```

or something similar to that.
And on my fedora it says

```
  Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)
```

By the way... both of them are running KDE.

Okay then i had a check on the `/dev` filesystem.
On my debian was as I expected a device file `dri/card0` in the `/dev` file system and of course on my fedora it is missing.

I also had a look on lsmod...
The module `drm` and its helper module are loaded on both machines.
Both machines use the i915 module for their graphic-cards.

My first thought was that fedora doesn't use direct rendering because there is no 'card0'. 
I used the linux tool `strace` to find out what is actually happening.
The results i got were not suprising
Debian loads the `drm library` and some other stuff. Then it checks if there is a `/dev/dri/card0` using the `stat` syscall. Then it opens it.
And starts to use loads of `ioctl` commands.
Thats how the `dri` mechanism should work.

So 'strace' on fedora brought the following result.

It opens the `drm library` as well. But it doesn't check if there is a `/dev/dri/card0` it starts to generate loads of output of `futex` calls.
I googled it and the futex call seems to offer the functionality for monitoring changes on a specific RAM address or multiple RAM addresses.
So there must be a reason that my fedora just don't want to use the `dri` mechanism.

PS The result looks on both machines the same.
But I really would like to know how to fix that issue.

Comment: On a properly configured system you have to do nothing. You will get a so called "direct rendering" context that uses GLX only to create an OpenGL context and bind into to the window. The actual OpenGL calls then will be made directly to the OpenGL driver, bypassing the X-Server going directly to the GPU where possible.

Comment: okay i am running fedora and the DRM kernel modul is loaded but there is no /dev/dri/*. Do i have to create it with mknod?

Comment: What GPU are you using? In case you're using NVidia or AMD with the proprietary drivers, then Direct Rendering happens through these proprietary drivers with their own kernel interfaces. DRM and DRI are relevant only for the open source drivers. What you really need to check is the output of `glxinfo | grep direct`.

Comment: I edited the question to describe what the actual problem is. I hope the informations are helpful.

Comment: This looks a lot like an improperly setup graphics environment, namely not all drivers having been installed; the `llvmpipe' renderer is the software implementation, which is the fallback if no drivers for the GPU are loaded. What's the output of `lsmod`? And could you please also post the contents of `/var/log/X.org.*.log`? – however we're quickly leaving StackOverflow land here and are venturing towards SuperUser.

Comment: i guess i found the reason inside `/var/log/X.org.0.log`. `Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable` My screen is just not good enough :(

Comment: I'd not throw the towel so fast. I'd wager on an improperly installed X.org environment. That message can pop up also if the X server couldn't load the DRI modules properly.

Comment: `open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory` those lines has been logged earlier than the other lines maybe i just need to add the /dev/dri/card0 to the `udev` rules. but that seems to really complicated.

Comment: Fedora seems to have the kernel parameter `nomodeset` as a default that diesabled the kernel mode settin which is necessary for `DRI`. So i removed that kernel parameter and voila my Desktop never looked that beautiful. OpenGL is running fast without making my fan explode.